# How do I assign variables in matrices?

Tags: octave

I can't make matrices with variables in it for some reason. I get following message.

```
>>> A= [a b ;(-1-a) (1-b); (1+a) b]

error: horizontal dimensions mismatch (2x3 vs 1x1)
```

Why is it? Please show me correct way if I'm wrong.

Comment: How are a and b defined in your code? If I enter `syms a b` and then paste in your command, it works fine.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Oh yes, Thanks for that. May be that's why I receive an error. I didn't define them. I just wanted to do some matrix calculations in terms of a,b so I have solution in them. But If want to do that, for example if I want the solution for A^2 in terms of a and b. how can I go for it. thanks.

Comment: If a and b are scalars, your matrix is rectangular, so A^2 is not defined. If it was defined, you would have simply given the command `A^2` to evaluate.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato well I just defined a as a matrix previously but not for this. suppose A = [x y], this is a 1*2 matrix. now when you type this in matlab you will have error >>> A=[x y]
error: 'x' undefined near line 1 column 4. I need that to be fixed. thanks

Comment: Is this octave? In that case you should add an octave tag

Comment: @lochana please enter the full session so that people can replicate your problem. `a = 5; b = 6; A = [a b ;(-1-a) (1-b); (1+a) b]` works as expected in Octave.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab you first need to assign a variable before you can use it,

```
a = 1;
b = a+1;
```

This will thus give an error,

```
clear;
b = a+1; % ERROR! Undefined function or variable 'a
```

Matlab does never accept unassigned variables. This is because, on the lowest level, you do not have `a`. You will have machine code which is assgined the value of `a`. This is handled by the JIT compiler in Matlab, so you do not need to worry about this though.

If you want to use something as the **variable** which you have in maths you can specifically express this to matlab. The object is called a `sym` and the syntax that define the `sym` **x** to a variable `x`is,

```
syms x;
```

That said, you can define a vector or a matrix as,

```
syms a b x y; % Assign the syms
A = [x y]; % Vector
B = A= [a b ;(-1-a) (1-b); (1+a) b]; % Matrix.
```

The size of a matrix can be found with `size(M)` or for dim n `size(M,n)`. You can calcuate the matrix product **M3=M1*M2** if and only if **M1** have the size **m * n** and **M2** have the size **n * p**. The size of **M3** will then be **m * p**. This will also mean that the operation **A^N = A * A * ...** is only allowed when **m=n** so to say, the matrix is square. This can be verified in matlab by the comparison,

```
syms a b
A = [a,1;56,b]
if size(A,1) == size(A,2)
    disp(['A is a square matrix of size ', num2str(size(A,1)]);
else
    disp('A is not square');
end
```

These are the basic rules for assigning variables in Matlab as well as for matrix multiplication. Further, a google search on the error **error: 'x' undefined** does only give me octave hits. Are you using octave? In that case I cannot guarantee that you can use `sym` objects or that the syntaxes are correct.

Comment: Yes I use octave. How did you know that?

Comment: @lochana I did a google search on the error message. I have never used octave and I did not recoginze the error from Matlab. However, if my answer does not work you should add an octave tag to the question and also add a comment that this does not work for octave.

Comment: @patrik this works fine for Octave. The problem is how the user defined `a` and `b` (I'm guessing they are not scalars.

Comment: @carandraug That is what I suppose as well, thereby the matrix part of the answer. However, since I get no response from lochana it is hard to give further advice.